# Python "TabError:" with elif statements

Tags: python, linux

I'm using Python with a raspberry pi (on Linux), and I'm trying to create the simplest main menu.
I keep getting this message when I add anything after the 1st elif (even an else):

```
 File "./mainmenu(1).py", line 24
    elif selection==3:
                     ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

my code is

```
def menu_main() :
    print("1.Activate monitor")
    print("2.Test sms_sender")
    print("3.Test email_sender")
    print("4.Start scanning")
    print("5.exit")
    while True:
        try:
            selection=int(input("What would you like to do: "))
            if selection==1:
              wlan1.monitor_set()
            elif selection==2:
              sms_sender.SMS_sender()
            elif selection==3:
              email_sender.email_sender()
        except ValueError:
            print("invalid chouise")
    exit
if __name__ == '__main__' :
  menu_main()
```

Comment: That error means you indented some lines with spaces, and other lines with tabs.  Don't do that.  Use all tabs or all spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because after if statement you have indented with 2 spaces, but at the other places, it's 4 spaces. Use consistent indentation throughout.

PEP 8 - python style guide suggests the use of 4 spaces for indentation. [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

Comment: Yes,thank you! 
It was a dumb mistake, I only noticed later on when I imported it on a IDE instead of the vim .